# Android: How to change which resource folder to choose for specific dimension or density device?

Tags: android

My problem is that I have to put identical copy of drawables for both drawable-mdpi and drawable-tvdpi.
Target devices density are tvdpi and xhdpi.
I want that device(xhdpi) fatch drawable resources from drawable-mdpi rather then drawable-tvdpi. For this what I need to do? And how? May be by custom build file it can be solved, but don't know how to do that?

Comment: You don't choose. The app chooses basing on the device properties.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you reference @drawable/image, the system selects the appropriate bitmap based on the screen's density.

```
 res/
    drawable-xhdpi/
       image.png
    drawable-tvdpi/
       image.png
```

So you need not do anything for the device to fetch the appropriate drawable resources .
Only thing is to add the image properly in the folder with standard pixel size .